# How to delay something in c#

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm working on a game where the player can drop a bomb. I want the bomb to flash for a second before exploding so the player has time to run away. The only solution I've found is "sleep", but the player can't move while the thread is paused so that doesn't work. Would it be stupid to open a new thread and use sleep? There could be an instance of multiple bombs going off at once.
I'd also be using this method to gradually increase the hit range of the bomb as it explodes.
I'm working on monogame if that's relevant.

Comment: You should investigate the 'game loop' pattern in which the game is updated multiple times a second using a delta time using the state of the controllers at that time rather than waiting and reacting to input.

Comment: This book by Rob Miles is for XNA but the concepts are applicable to monogame and is a good gently introduction https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft%C2%AE-XNA%C2%AE-Game-Studio-3-0/dp/0735626588

Comment: @Josh ive been using the game loop (update) to get the input info with keyboard state, i dont quite understand what you mean?

Comment: a crude example would be to take the time that the bomb was placed and in the update frame have a switch that performs the logic like: if the bomb was dropped less than a second ago, paint the bomb with a white brush, if it's less than 2 sconds ago use a black brush, if its less than 3 seconds ago use a white brush etc... so it appears to flash. Then in the last case, something like if it's less than 5 seconds ago, perform the explosion logic

Comment: Many duplicates.  Let's take you [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81411/how-to-have-an-event-occur-after-x-seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong pattern here.

- You do not want to "wait" for the bomb to explode.
- What you need is for the the bomb to explode at a given time.

So, in your game logic, when you iterate over the state of your active game object you need to check the time between the time it was spawned and the current time then explose if the fuse time has elapsed :

```
If (Now() - SpawnTime >= Fusetime) { Boom(); }
```

You can even had more logic now. *eg : make the bomb flash/beep/shake if the remaining time is less than 1s. Or whatever you wish.*

```
else If (Now() - SpawnTime >= (Fusetime - 1)) { Beep(); }
```

Comment: If you want all your bomb to explode early  for some reason, just iterate over them and simply call your Boom() routine regardless of fuse time. Or force the fuseTime to be negative and they'll explode at the next game cycle.